# Call javascript function after specific time intervals

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

I am writing code for JavaScript.In which I am trying to check the remote asp.net page(aspx) connection using AJAX.But also I want to check the condition that, this call will continue for 2 Minute only and with 10 sec time intervals.
not that but like that logic I am thinking,
If flag=true
   if seconds < 120
      setInterval("GetFeed()", 2000);

can anybody please help me for that.

Here is my code of Connection check,

```
            var learnerUniqueID1;
        var flag='true';

        function fnCheckConnectivity(coursId) 
        {
            //here will the remote page url
            var url = 'http://<%=System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.Host+System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath%>/TestConn.aspx'; 
            //alert(url);
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                learnerUniqueID1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
                learnerUniqueID1 = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Your browser does not support XMLHTTP!");
            }
            learnerUniqueID1.open("POST", url, true);
            learnerUniqueID1.onreadystatechange = callbackZone;
            learnerUniqueID1.send(null);
        }

        function callbackZone() 
        {
            if (learnerUniqueID1.readyState == 4) 
            {
                if (learnerUniqueID1.status == 200) 
                {
                    //update the HTML DOM based on whether or not message is valid
                    parseMessageZone();
                }
                else
                {   
                    flag='false';                       
                    alert('We have detected a break in your web connection, \n please login again to continue with your session');
                }
            }
        }

        function parseMessageZone() 
        {
            var result = learnerUniqueID1.responseText;
        }        

        function makePayment(obj)
        {
            try
            {
                var Id = obj.attributes["rel"].value
                //alert(Id);
                var res=confirm('Want to Continue.');
                if(res == true)
                {
                    startRequest(Id);
                    //return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            catch(Error)
            {

            }
        }

        function startRequest(Id)
        {
            var milliseconds = 10000;
            currentDate = new Date();
            // start request
            pollRequest(milliseconds, false, currentDate, 120000,Id);
        }

        function pollRequest(milliseconds, finshed, date, timeout,Id)
        {
            if((new Date()).getTime() > date.getTime()+timeout)
            {
                // 2-minute timeout passed
                return;
            }
            if(!finished){
                  setTimeout(function(){
                     if(//check backend to see if finished)     //which method will go here
                     {   
                        fnCheckConnectivity(coursId);
                         pollRequest(milliseconds, true, date, timeout,Id);
                     }
                     else{
                         pollRequest(milliseconds, false, date, timeout,Id)
                     }
                  }, milliseconds);
                  return;
            }
            // when code reaches here, request has finished

        }
```

Comment: Are you using any libraries? It would make writing a proof of concept a lot faster.

Comment: so you are trying to determine the connection is up for 2 continuous minutes, and then wait for 10 seconds and re-try?

Comment: no,the scenario is,User click on some button then I call the JS function and in that function I need to call one page for some response and this call need go for every after 10 sec within continuous 2 minute.This minutes start when the first hit of the JS function.Also when I receive any response from remote page I need to quit otherwise continue until 2 minutes end and then quit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand correctly, but if you are trying to poll the status of a request you made every ten seconds, why not try something like this?

```
function startRequest(){
    var milliseconds = 10000;
    currentDate = new Date();
    timeout = 120000;
    // start request
    pollRequest(milliseconds, false, currentDate, timeout);
}

function pollRequest(milliseconds, finshed, date, timeout){

    if((new Date()).getTime() > date.getTime()+timeout){
        // 2-minute timeout passed
        return;
    }

    if(!finished){
          setTimeout(function(){
             if(//check backend to see if finished){
                 pollRequest(milliseconds, true, date, timeout);
             }
             else{
                 pollRequest(milliseconds, false, date, timeout)
             }
          }, milliseconds);
          return;
    }

    // when code reaches here, request has finished
}
```

Please note this is a recursive function and browsers have a recursion limit. Also, regarding the 2 minute timeout, you can either set the timeout as an ajax prefilter or add a variable that is added on each recursion.

Comment: thank you,can you please elaborate how I will check 2 Min end using above one ?

Comment: Give me a sec, I'll edit my answer to incorporate a Date comparison

Comment: Well I don't know the service you are calling, but just replace the comments with actions (e.g., //start request with the actual function that starts the request). My guess is that to check if it is finished just do readyState == 4 or something similar. But again, it depends on your service, just adapt the code to fit your code.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly to want to do a task for 2 minutes every 10 seconds.

```
var interval = setInterval(function(){
// do stuff
},10000); // execute every 10 seconds

setTimeout(function(){
    clearInterval(interval);
},120000); // Remove interval after 2 minutes
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want a script running continuously on a server/client. You should look up chronjob for linux or scheduler for windows.

I didn't give you a proper solution, just an alternative. For what you seem to want to do, however, this seems like the right tool.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a push request that you're describing, in which the client user waits for a certain amount of time and then makes a request, you should use a pull request.

To do that, you can make an AJAX call to the sever, and then the sever can wait (and possibly do something else while waiting) and then return something to the user when data is ready.